# Passing method generic type to internal call

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a method with generics to unmarshal JSON lists into lists containing POJOs. The snippet below compiles and runs, but at runtime I am getting my `List<CustomPojo>` filled with `HashMap` instances, as the type T is not passed along to the `TypeReference` constructor which then falls back to `HashMap` I guess.

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(String endpoint) throws IOException {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVER_ADDRESS + endpoint);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    try {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return mapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(), new TypeReference<List<T>>() { });
        }
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Am I on the right track or is this something not achievable using generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
    mapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(),
    mapper.getTypeFactory().contructCollectionType(List.class, cls);
```

where *`cls`* is *`Class<T>`* it should works.

Comment: +1 Thanks @bodo, this has in fact fixed the issue, but I was really asking about the generics related behavior (which is why I did not add Jackson to the question title or tags). This also means adding the class as an additional method parameter.

Comment: I don't think it's achievable by using a generics, that's why I have suggested you the solution posted above.